# Render openlayers angular directive ol-marker freezes browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

Based on [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/), When I call `ol-marker` to the display, the browser freeze because I load too many points at the same time. It seems, canvas rendering in openlayers will give up after few hundred point of `ol-marker` rendered.

I have create the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw11g639/) that show the problem. I wonder if there is a good solution for it?

edit: to be able to load the data, you should allowed cors in your browser

Comment: do you find something since you posted this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I consider migrating to leaflet, or the other alternative, put the data into kml files that loaded into the map layers

Comment: which ol version do you have ? i had the same issue but the last version solve it (it's still very slow)

Comment: the OL version is 3.10.1

Comment: try with the las one